# Como generar código consecutivo que no se duplique al hacer dos peticiones en simultáneo

Tags: vb.net

Estoy generando un consecutivo trayendo el último ID de la tabla y sumandole 1, el problema es que si se realiza la petición mas de una vez al mismo tiempo, el código seria el mismo para las peticiones que se hagan.

```
Dim ULTIMO As Integer, CONT As Integer, ID_GENERADO As Integer
        Dim conexion As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PSMVSConnectionFinal").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(conexion)
            con.Open()
            Dim consulta As String = "Select TOP 1 ID_MANTENIMIENTO From MANTENIMIENTO Order By ID_MANTENIMIENTO DESC"
            Dim comando As New SqlCommand(consulta, con)
            Dim leer As SqlDataReader = comando.ExecuteReader()
            If leer.Read() = True Then
                txtGet_ID.Text = leer("ID_MANTENIMIENTO").ToString()
            End If
        End Using
        ULTIMO = Integer.Parse(txtGet_ID.Text)
        CONT = 1
        ID_GENERADO = ULTIMO + CONT
        txtSet_ID.Text = ID_GENERADO
```

Answer (score 1):

---

Saludos,

Las bases de datos ponen a disposición el campo auto-numérico, el cuál se encargará de sumarle 1 a cada nuevo registro que hagas a esa tabla, así que no hace falta que hagas eso en tu programa.

Por otro lado, sería normal esperar que el ID generado sea el mismo (ya que si dos programas se abren al mismo tiempo en tu formulario para insertar un nuevo registro, seleccionará el último ID disponible, es decir, en ambos casos sería `ULTIMO + 1`) así que lo más conveniente es que sea la base de datos quién te retorne ese ID.

En cualquier caso, miremos este método: [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3).

Explícitamente nos indica:

> The function returns the new Identity column value if a new row was
>   inserted, 0 on failure.

Es decir:

> La función retorna un nuevo valor de identidad de la columna si una nueva fila es insertada, retorna 0 si no se pudo agregar.

Básicamente, es una función para agregar una nueva categoría de producto, lo único que necesitamos es la descripción de esa nueva categoría, así que nos olvidaremos del ID (ya que será la base de datos quién la generará). En tu caso es algo similar, le pasas todos los datos necesarios, excepto el de la columna ID.

Esta línea `newProdID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())` es la que nos permite retornar el ID autogenerado por la base de datos. Luego, sólo deberás ajustar ese nuevo valor autogenerado a tu variable.

De esa manera, si dos aplicaciones están abiertas en el mismo formulario al mismo tiempo y ambas insertan un nuevo registro en tu base de datos, se generará el ID del registro que llegue primero, y al momento justo que llega el siguiente registro, se generará el siguiente, y así sucesivamente.

El único inconveniente es que si quisieras agregar un campo ID en tu formulario para que el usuario final sepa cuál es el ID del nuevo registro no es posible hacerlo, sino hasta después de realizar el `INSERT`. (Yo lo solucioné mostrando un mensaje que mostraba dicho consecutivo)

---

PD: Me disculpo por no poder dar más detalles, no tengo Visual Studio instalado en este momento, sin embargo he probado realizar lo mismo en Java y me ha funcionado de maravilla (ya que la lógica de programación es casi la misma para cualquier lenguaje, asumí que existe una manera de retornar valores autogenerados).

**PD 2: Como indicación de @gbianchi, al utilizar este método se asume que se utilizará únicamente para realizar inserciones a la tabla, ya que se retornará la primera fila de la primera columna (es decir, se espera sólo un valor de retorno), en caso de utilizar con otras sentencias como `SELECT`, normalmente se esperarían más registros, así que eso generaría un problema.**

Comment: LA respuesta no es mala. Pero esta incorrecta. ExecuteScalar retorna el valor de la primera fila y primera columna del query que se ejecute. Si el query, es un insert, entonces si retorna el nuevo valor de Identidad. Si es un select, devuelve otra cosa. Creo que habria que aclarar mucho mejor esa parte.

Comment: La idea es utilizar `INSERT` (ya que el caso es al momento de insertar nuevos registros) y no para otras cosas por eso no tomé en cuenta el `SELECT` pero es un excelente aporte.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario mostrar el `ID` de tu tabla ya que por buenas prácticas este debe ser autonumérico y se debe obtener luego de su inserción. Sino va a pasar el problema que acabas de describir por la concurrencia que pueda ocurrir.

Comment: Podría utilizar otra columna de la tabla como por ejemplo CODIGO, el punto es que si realizo la consulta al ultimo registro en CODIGO y le sumo 1, me creará el numero consecutivo, pero si al mismo tiempo abro otra pestaña el consecutivo se pierde por que el último registro en CODIGO es el mismo para las dos peticiones.