# Facturas con consecutivo multiusuario

Tags: c#

Buena como puede controlar uno cuando 2 personas intentan guardar una factura en el mismo instante en mysql o en sql. Ya intente con autonumericos y con max(id), tambien intente con un contador en una tabla pero siempre lanza una excepcion cuando se intenta acceder al mismo tiempo desde 2 pc. Hay alguna forma o algun algoritmo para controlar eso y que se asignen consecutivos validos sin perder consecutivos en el camino?

Comment: Tienes que aplicar un `LOCK` en la tabla al momento de hacer un `UPDATE`.  Chequea este link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables-restrictions.html

Comment: gracias parece buena idea esa. Abra algun tutorial pero en español?  Me imagino que la idea ahi seria comprobar si la tabla esta bloqueda y esperar pero en ese caso como podria indicar en el programa que espere a que se desbloquee la tabla?

Comment: Aqui hay un link en esta pagina: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152681/evitar-un-insert-concurrente/152701#152701

Comment: También podrías intentar esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/179931/66587 El ejemplo del método está para VB.NET, pero en esa página también está el ejemplo para C#

Comment: Es importante añadir a la pregunta el código de los intentos y los errores que arroja. ¿Cuál es la excepción? Así como está, las posibles respuestas son muy amplias.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto suena a un error de codificación mas que de concurrencia, seria bueno que pudieras poner el código que utilizas para abrir la conexión a la base de datos, si intentas usar la misma conexión para guardar los datos al mismo tiempo es probable que tengas el problema que mencionas, te recomiendo implementar un modelo fabrica sobre un singelton para prevenir el problema:

```
public static class DataFactory
{
    public static SqlConnection GetConexion(string connectionString)
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();

        return connection;
    }
}
```

Y la implementas asi:

```
public class Repository
{
    public void DataOperation()
    {
        //Con using aseguras que tu conexion se cierre una vez que termina tu metodo o funcion
        using(var connection = DataFactory.GetConexion("tucadenadeconexion"))
        {
            /*Tu logica*/
        }
    }
}
```

También te recomiendo leer un poco sobre las diferencias de una clase estática y no estática.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80103/discussion-on-answer-by-augusto-diaz-facturas-con-consecutivo-multiusuario).